# Remote conan repository in Artifactory C++ edition does not find some packages that are in the referenced repository

Tags: c++, artifactory, conan

I'm using Artifactory Community edition for C++ with the intention of caching some repositories, such as conan-center, as well as having a local repository for my own conan recipes.

Currently I have configured 3 remote repositories as in the image below
[image]

After that I created a virtual repository that includes all 3 remote repositories as well as a local repository (currently without any package).

After configure the conan client to add my virtual repository I can run `conan search` as below

```sh
conan search hdf5 -r=all
```

This results in

```
Remote 'conan-center':
hdf5/1.8.21
hdf5/1.10.5
hdf5/1.10.6
hdf5/1.12.0
Remote 'artifactory':
hdf5/1.8.21
hdf5/1.10.5
hdf5/1.10.6
hdf5/1.12.0
```

which is expected, since artifactory is including the remote repository for conan-center.

However, some packages seem to not be found in the artifactory virtual remote, while they are found in conan-center. For instance, the command

```sh
conan search fmt -r=all
```

results in

```
Remote 'conan-center':
fmt/4.0.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/4.1.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.0.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.1.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.2.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.2.1@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.3.0
fmt/5.3.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/6.0.0
fmt/6.0.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/6.1.0
fmt/6.1.1
fmt/6.1.2
fmt/6.2.0
fmt/6.2.1
fmt/7.0.1
fmt/7.0.2
fmt/7.0.3
fmt/7.1.0
fmt/7.1.1
fmt/7.1.2
fmt/7.1.3
Remote 'artifactory':
fmt/4.0.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/4.1.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.0.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.1.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.2.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.2.1@bincrafters/stable
fmt/5.3.0@bincrafters/stable
fmt/6.0.0@bincrafters/stable
```

At first I thought that maybe the remote functionality in artifactory didn't work with packages without the "@user/channel" part, since the search found the versions with "@bincrafters/stable", but after testing with the HDF5 library, which does not have "@user/channel" it worked as I have shown before.

Is there something I'm missing?

---

Note: In the remote repository configuration in artifactory I'm using "conan-default" as both the "Repository Layout" and the "Remote Layout Mapping".

Comment: I am a bit confused, the command reads exactly the same ``conan search hdf5 -r=all``, but leads to completely different results. Did you mean ``conan search fmt -r=all`` the second one?

Comment: Is it just the search? Can you do a ``conan install fmt/version -r=myvirtual``?

Comment: That command (with replaced version and remote name) fails with `ERROR: Conanfile not found at <current_working_directory>/fmt/7.1.3`.

But I could confirm that it is not just when searching by removing the fmt library from my local cache, leaving only my artifactory server in my `remotes.json` file, and trying to install dependencies again (specified in a conanfile.py file). Then I get the error 
`ERROR: Version range '>=7.1.3' from requirement 'fmt/[>=7.1.3]' required by 'conanfile.py (package name/0.1)' could not be resolved in local cache`
If I include the conan-center remote it works.

Comment: I have also edited the question to fix the typing error in the second command (from hdf5 do fmt).

Comment: Sorry, I meant ``conan install fmt/7.1.3@ -r=myvirtual`` there was a typo, and the @ was missing.

Comment: If it sounds like a bug, maybe it would be worth to report to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/ issues